# Spring Cloud Zuul - Add http proxy details (proxy server, proxy port, credentials etc) to the incoming request before routing

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

We are planning to build a reverse proxy server for our enterprise to make some external API calls.

Currently, our microservice applications are hosted on the PCF environment. For any external (on the internet) calls, we make use of the PCF proxy server to communicate.
Now my use-case is to build a reverse proxy server(Spring Zuul) to route to external APIs through the PCF proxy. However, the microservice applications wouldn't pass any proxy information on the request to the zuul server. So, this needs to be added by Spring Zuul reverse proxy server.

**Problem:**

How to add HTTP proxy details to the coming request from zuul server?

Any documentation also would be really helpful.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to tell who's making calls to where and zuul fits in.

Comment: Thanks @spencergibb for the quick response. We have the set of external API URLs for which Zuul proxy needs to add HTTP proxy details. Can we achieve this using either 'pre' or 'route' filter?

Comment: add proxy details as what? headers?

Comment: Is it possible to add proxy details in the headers from zuul? If so will it go via the proxy server to the destination host. Apologies if it doesn't relates to your question.

Comment: @spencergibb Is it possible to customize or override 'SimpleHostRoutingFilter' in the zuul proxy server?